# Delete the only node from a BST

Tags: c++

My BST have only ONE node. I wrote a code to delete that node but it's still there. Just like it hasn't been... updated. Here is my simple code, just to test the case

```
void Delete(BSTree* tree, int& key)
{
    if (key == tree->key)
        tree=NULL;
}
```

And my BSTree class doesn't have a parrent part. Just the value and the left and right pointer. What is wrong with my code? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You aren't changing the actual `tree` pointer. You're only changing the pointer that was allocated on the stack, pointing to the same address as the passed-in pointer.

You want `BSTree *&tree` so that you get the reference to the original pointer, so that any changes effect it.

As Als points out, don't forget to free memory in addition to the above.

Comment: And one more thing, I have a code to display the tree and if it's NULL I will cout<<NULL; but it's just like an...empty tree not a NULL one?

Comment: It depends on what `NULL` means to your tree. In your display function, you should most likely stop at `NULL` before actually displaying it (you're clearly stopping before trying to process it, or else it would crash).

Comment: In that case, then I don't get the question. If you want to actually display each `NULL` leaf, then do what you're doing, but you'll have to do a special check against the root node to determine emptiness in that case.